# How to pass variables and methods as command line arguments in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a scenario. I have to pass the parameter values to the methods in script and methods to execute.

Example:

File name app.py

```
value1 = sys.argv[1]
value2 = sys.argv[2]
def method1():
    print(value1)

def method2():
    print(value2)
```

Command I am trying to execute: `python3 app.py 10 12 method2`

In the above the output should be `method2()` print value is **12**

Comment: `argv` would be `["app.py", "10", "12", "method2"]`. so if you want access the `"method2"` argument pass `argv[3]` not `argv[2]`

Comment: You should check [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/argparse.html) it is pretty easy to use and will become handy as soon as you have multiple command line arguments to retrieve

Comment: But it's still unclear to me what exactly you're trying to achieve. are you trying to choose which function to invoke via the command line arguments?

Comment: @Tibebes.M Basically I need to pass the argument to execute either method1 function or method2 function alone or both functions. When we pass the argument as method1, It should execute only method1 function. If we pass method 1 and method 2 in command arguments . It should execute both the functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can reference the function to call dynamically (from the local symbol table using [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals))

```
import sys


def method1(value1, value2):
    print(value1)


def method2(value1, value2):
    print(value2)


def method_not_found(*args, **kwargs):
    print('[-] function not found')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    locals().get(sys.argv[3], 'method_not_found')(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

```
user@pc: python a.py 10 12 method1

10
```

```
user@pc: python a.py 10 12 method13

[-] function not found
```

**Explanation:**
the way the line:

```
locals().get(sys.argv[3], 'method_not_found')(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

works is that [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) return a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) type and we're calling [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to get refer to the function we're gonna call (if not found, get `method_not_found` function instead).

Then after we get the function we want to call, we execute it by passing `sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]` as arguments.

Comment: Can we call a method like method1(value1,value2) using the locals()

Comment: Of course you can. `local()` is just there to get a reference to the function. the last `()` is where you invoke the function. just pass any argument you want there.

Comment: see the updated answer to get an idea, also make sure to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import sys
def method1():
    print(sys.argv[1])
def method2():
    print(sys.argv[2])
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.argv[3] == 'method1':
        method1()
    elif sys.argv[3] == 'method2':
        method2()
    else:
        print("Invalid argument")
```

Executed as :

```
python app.py 10 12 method1
>> 10
python app.py 10 12 method2
>> 12
```

Comment: Can we call something like this
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.argv[3] == 'method1':
        sys.argv[3] ()

Comment: no because `argv[3]` is a **string** - not a `Callable` type. Although not recommended you can get a reference to the function from the lookup table by making use of [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) or `globals()`

Comment: see the answer I've posted to see how